# Find the derivative of $f(x)=(15\sqrt{x}+5)^2$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Find the derivative of $f(x)=(15\sqrt{x}+5)^2$ and determine $f'(9)$

So far I factor it so I got $f(x) = 225x+150\sqrt{x}+25$.

Now I did some of the derivatives rules where $\frac{d}{dx}225x$=225 and $\frac{d}{dx}25=0$

So I have $225+\frac{d}{dx}150\sqrt{x}+0$

So to is there a derivative rule for the square root or do I just plug in 9 or did I do something wrong.

Please Help!!!

Comment: If $k$ is any constant, then the derivative of $x^k$ is $kx^{k-1}$. We have $\sqrt{x}=x^{1/2}$. The derivative of $\sqrt{x}$ is therefore $(1/2)x^{-1/2}$.

Comment: Just a heads up: $225+150\sqrt{x}+0$ is not an equation. An equation is on the form $A=B$ where A and B are expressions.

Comment: I deleted my obsolete preaching.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The derivative of $\sqrt{x}$ folows the same power rule as polynomials. $\sqrt{x}=x^{\frac{1}{2}}$ so that the derivative is $\frac{1}{2} x^{\frac{-1}{2}}=\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{x}}$. Thus, the derivative of your function becomes $225+\frac{150}{2 \sqrt{x}}$

Answer (score 0):

$$f'(x)=\left((15\sqrt x+5)^2\right)'=2(15\sqrt x+5)^{2-1}(15\sqrt x+5)'=(15\sqrt{x}+5)\frac{15}{\sqrt x}$$ 
$$f'(9)=(15\cdot3+5)\frac{15}{3}=250$$